How do I mount a disk using MacFUSE?
I have an old harddisk that's formatted as HFS, which I would like to read on my modern Mac that runs Ventura. I've got the physical connection covered: I've connected the HD via a SATA/PATA to USB bridge to my Mac.
The next step is to read the filesystem. I've installed macFUSE and fuseHFS.
But neither of those software packages comes with ANY documentation.
How do I get this disk to show up in the Finder?

https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/FAQ

The FAQ does not answer that question.

This is what I was able to find out through trial and error.
When you connect a disk while MacFUSE and fuseHFS are installed:

The disk will not show up in the Finder sidebar.
Disk Utility will show the disk, and shows that the disk is mounted.
Disk Utility can format the disk. When fuseHFS is installed, it can format as HFS.

To access the disk: in the Finder, go to the /Volumes folder. The disk is visible there. Files can be copied from/to the disk.
